# Advanced search is not supported

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, android-app

I tried searching using these: `title:android`, `user:me`, `answers:0`, but they don't seem to work. I get incorrect results.

**Edit #1:** The filter I used (at the right-side dropdown) was `Active`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be either [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request]? <- those tags did not show up how I wanted them to, but you get the idea.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ I edited the tag to bug. I leave it up to them to change to feature request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug in our API backend that was recently fixed.

Now most advanced search options should work the same way in the mobile app as they do on the website.

[image]

[image]