# Browse by category / tag

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When reading a post in the app, the categories / tags are shown below the question and in the ListView as well. I would really like to be able to browse all questions with a specific tag (or a selection of tags, which seems to be a bit more difficult)

Are there any plans on implementing browsing by category / tag in the android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When viewing a site's questions you can use the search at the top to search for a tag by enclusing it in square brackets, for example `[asp.net]`.

The android app should be [mostly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192545/advanced-search-is-not-supported) in line with the [website's search features](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: When viewing a question's content and answers there is no search bar visible. I can only enter search terms in the question list.

Comment: Being able to click on tags would be helpful to me

Comment: See this feature request regarding clicking on tags (upvote it if you like): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191596/clicking-tag-in-question-should-present-a-list-of-questions As you see it's planned, but not implemented yet.

Comment: Oh, this is exactly what I would like to see in the app. Thanks